# How to configure separate active directories to support multiple environments in web application in AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I need to have separate active directories for each environment in my project (dev, stg, prd etc.), so if the user will create his local account in one environment it will be only in its related active directory and if the same email is used for sign up on different env - another account should be created. Are there some guidelines to achieve such a goal and if there are any downsides of such an approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different B2C tenants for each environment.

But the users are unique to each tenant.

The same user can be in both tenants.

But if joe@test.com logs into both tenants, the issuer (tenant.onmicrosoft.com) in the JWT returned will be different so you can tell the difference.